# Google Now screen is blank (Nexus 7, Android 4.2)

Tags: nexus-7, google-now

I've got a Nexus 7 upgraded to Android 4.2. When I swipe up from the home button to launch Google Now I just get a blank screen with a search bar at the top. I don't see the "Get Google Now" screen shown [here](http://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-setup-configure-and-use-google-now-98749/) or any options to add new cards.

[image]

How can I go about getting the Google Now setup screen?

Answer (score 3):

Invoke Google Now again to be in the same place as is on your snapshot. Just press Back button to hide keyboard and press three dots button bottom right and select Settings. You will get the summary where you can realize that you have Google Now switched Off. Just select this item and continue with the wizard to switch Google Now On.